# relog not working via t-sql xp_commandshell but same command working on command prompt

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, t-sql, perfmon

Below command is working fine on command prompt and ps but giving error via t-sql, is there any solution around this ?

```
set @command=  'relog'+' "'+@loctoreaddata+'"'+ '-cf '+ '"'+'N:\Perfcounterlist\'+'test.txt'+'"'+' -f SQL -o SQL:Perfdata!SQLDEMO1'
        exec    xp_cmdshell @command
```

Below error in sql
Error: To relog multiple files all files must be in binary format.

Below in win events

> Call to SQLAllocConnect failed with [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

out put of select @command for reference

```
relog "N:\PerfMonAutomation\MasterActive.blg"-cf "N:\Perfcounterlist\test.txt" -f SQL -o SQL:Perfdata!SQLDEMO1
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this from SQL Server, using `xp_cmdshell` in the first place? Feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.com) if I am honest.

Comment: Because there are multiple variable i am taking it from sql tables and assigning it to relog as parameter

Comment: Is the DSN you specify ("Perfdata!SQLDEMO1") per user or per system. And, are you running the `relog` from the command line as the same user that runs the SQL Server process?

Comment: So you're **unsecurely** injecting these values? You have an even bigger problem than I thought then. This is wide open to SQL Injection. Combine that with `xp_cmdshell` and you have a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Christian.K its user DSN created on system and sql is running with other account and command line under another account

Comment: @Larnu is there an another way o achieve this ?

Comment: I would start by at least using `QUOTENAME` on the dynamic value, or `REPLACE` if the value can be over 128 characters.

Comment: As my solution was working on powershell i returned the variable from sql and run it via powershell console and then it was working fine but when i scheduled the sql job the same issue persist again even i tried to call as ps file from task scheduler as well but no luck, here is ps i developed     $insertquery=@" 
exec PerfMon_AutoMation
"@
        $QueryResult= Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'TestServer' -query $insertquery  -Database dba 
              
                $Test= $QueryResult.Runnablecmd
                $Test
                relog $Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Error: To relog multiple files all files must be in binary format"
All this means is that the files you're working with are different kinds, and they don't get along with each other.
If a file is created and something changes within, it gets updated. Even when saved as the same type of file (especially .CSV files), the binary code changes.
Find what's being changed between file creation and your script, and you'll find the issue. For example, CSV file opened with excel, and then saved as CSV file again (warning: some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as a CSV).